# Setting dynamic fallback in jquery each with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to set a fallback function dynamically from an ajax jsonp call, but it doesn't seem to work - I am actually not quite sure if it is even possible -  at least I believe I am doing it wrong.

I have this

```
 var GetFacebookData = function (data) {

        var dates = [{ "date_from": data.date_from, "date_to": data.date_to }]

        $.each(data.datatypes, function (i, index) {

            this.fbcallback[data.datatypes[i]["id"]] = function () {
                LoadFacebookData(dates, data.datatypes["id"]);
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:59380/' + data.datatypes[i]["urlfile"] + '.php?jsonp=fbcallback' + data.datatypes[i]["id"],
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'fbcallback',
                data: { "lpage": _bankArea, "hashed_token": CryptoJS.MD5("454545").toString(), "date_from": data.date_from, "date_to": data.date_to },
            });

        });
    }
```

And I am calling the function with this

```
 GetFacebookData({ date_from: _datefrom, date_to: _dateto, datatypes: [{ id: "moedsparnord", urlfile: "index" }, { id: "studiepakken", urlfile: "fb_studiedata" }] });
```

I am just getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'moedsparnord' of undefined
```

The whole concept is that I will need to run `GetFacebookData` multiple times with difference data to be executed.

---

```
  /*** LOAD FETCHED DATA AS JSON ***/
    var LoadFacebookData = function (dates, id) {

        _dateLoader.hide();

        $('.date-box form').slideUp(750, 'easeOutBack');

        var pages = [];

        this.loadcallback = function (data) {

            var len = data["campaignData"].length;

            $.each(data["campaignData"], function (index, value) {

                $('#' + id + '-' + value["campaign"]["campaignId"]).find(".facebook").text(AddDecimal(value["campaign"]["campaignReach"]));
                $('#' + id + '-' + value["campaign"]["campaignId"]).find(".facebook").attr("data-spend", value["campaign"]["campaignSpend"]);

                if (index != len) {
                    pages[index] = [value["campaign"]["campaignId"], value["campaign"]["campaignSpend"]];
                }

            });

            var string = $('#' + id + ' .total-facebook').text().replace(/,/g, '');

            $("#" + id + " .total-facebook").countTo({
                from: parseFloat(string),
                to: data["totalReach"],
                decimals: 0,
                formatter: function (value, options) {

                    return value.toFixed(options.decimals).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
                },
            });

            MSNLeadData([{ date_from: dates[0]["date_from"], date_to: dates[0]["date_to"] }, pages]);
            StudieLeadData([{ date_from: dates[0]["date_from"], date_to: dates[0]["date_to"], pages }]);
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:59380/loaddata.php?jsonp=loadcallback',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'loadcallback',
            data: { "lpage": _bankArea, "hashed_token": CryptoJS.MD5("454545").toString(), "datatype": id },

        });
    }
```

Comment: the probleme is in your `LoadFacebookData(dates, data.datatypes["id"]);` function, can you post the code !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions `fbcallback['...']` should be global.

Try to use this code inside the loop.

```
...
var callbackName = 'fbcallback-' + data.datatypes[i]["id"];
window[callbackName] = function () {
            LoadFacebookData(dates, data.datatypes["id"]);
}
...
 $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:59380/' + data.datatypes[i]["urlfile"] + '.php',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: callbackName,
            data: { "lpage": _bankArea, "hashed_token": CryptoJS.MD5("454545").toString(), "date_from": data.date_from, "date_to": data.date_to },
        });
```

And inside of `LoadFacebookData` callback method should also be global (`window.loadcallback`).